# JPA ManyToOne field not getting stored

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, google-app-engine, jpa

I have a bean structure as shown below. The problem that I am facing is while trying to persist XBean, I am able to save all the data (i.e. xName, pBean, qBean, rBean, kBeans are all visible in storage) but there is no entry for Y_BEAN.

I am pretty much new with JPA annotations so not really sure if what I have done is correct. The idea is to have multiple entries of XBean (i.e. as List) with one instance of YBean

XBean also will hold an instance of YBean as its parent so when I retrieve XBean I should get all the data. Is there something wrong with `@ManyToOne` annotation?

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "X_BEAN")
public class XBean implements XInterface {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    private String xName;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private PBean pBean;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="y_id")
    private YBean yBean;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private qBean qBean;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private RBean rBean;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy="xBean", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<KBean> kBeans;

    // getter setters for each are below ...
}
```

and structure of YBean is like below

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "Y_BEAN")
public class YBean implements XInterface {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private ZBean zName;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private PBean pBean;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private RBean rBean;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy="yBean", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<XBean> xBeans;

    // getter setter for each are below ...
}
```

I am using Google App Engine's storage

Comment: What is the type of `Key` here ?

Comment: `Key` is `com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key`. I am using Google App Engine's storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST` on your `ManyToOne`, to tell Hibernate to persist the YBean when it persists the XBean.

You should also think about whether you want the cascade attribute on the inverse `OneToMany`.  With `CascadeType.ALL`, if you were to delete an instance of YBean, Hibernate will delete all associated XBeans (of which there may be zero, one, or many), because `CascadeType.ALL` means "apply persistence operations, including deletion, to any other entities accessible via this property or collection".  If you didn't have `CascadeType.ALL` and you deleted a YBean that was referred to by one or more XBeans, then those XBeans would now referenced a non-existent YBean ID, so you'd probably need to do some cleanup in that case.

Both options are irrelevant if your business logic never deletes a YBean until it is not referred to by any XBeans, but if your business logic doesn't prevent the case, then you should cascade or not based on whether you want to get rid of the XBeans or whether you want to clean them up (but not delete them) to no longer refer to the YBean that's being deleted.

Comment: using `cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST` worked but i didn't understood your second line. can you please explain a little in detail

Comment: thanks, that's pretty clear now. I guess in my case `CascaseType.ALL` for `OneToMany` case will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="y_id")
private YBean yBean;

what is the column y_id ?
what is the definition of it?

you can try removing @JoinColumn(name="y_id") and let JPA handle it.

and also add fetch = FetchType.EAGER like this.

@OneToMany (mappedBy="yBean", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<XBean> xBeans;
```

Comment: what `FetchType.Eager` will do in this case?

Comment: this makes sure.. when you load one object all its children will also be loaded during that time instead of waiting for you to make a call on that

Comment: Eager/lazy fetch optimization is a complex topic in its own right; there's no universal answer to what's the right option, and the OP didn't give any indication of what would be the needs in this case, so I don't see how you know that your eager-fetching suggestion will make things better instead of worse.

Comment: I have been dealing with Eager/Lazy all along in my work using suitable ones when needed considering the performance. I agree it's a complex topic. But to your questions why you are not seeing the instance of YBEAN loaded (which is a parent) when you retrieve XBEAN. This Fetch type might be the reason.

Comment: I think you may have misread the question.  The OP wants to know why YBeans aren't persisted when an XBean that refers to them is persisted.  Retrieval of already-persisted entities wasn't the issue here.

Comment: well.. that brings up a question, can you have XBEAN with out a parent YBEAN. if NO.. use the annotation like this @ManyToOne(optional = false), if it's optional, then you need to create the YBEAN first and set in XBEAN instance and persist. To my knowledge, cascaded persistence is recommended from parent YBEAN.